# Raspberry PI 3 USB to Serial Communication

Tags: c, raspberry-pi

I have done the loopback on the USB to Serial on the **Raspbery PI3** , i have done the coding in C for configuring the port (`ttyUSB0`) , Set the `baudrate:9600, Parity:None,Databits:8` , and i have loopbacked the pins `2 (rx) and 3(tx) on DB9 Connector`

2) during debugging i got to know raspberry **PI3** is writing only 5 bits of data not 8 bits.

**Example :**

1)  if write the value as "`A`" i will get in binary value read as "`000001`" not as "`00000001`"

2) if i write the value as "d" i will get in binary value read as "`00100`" not as "`01100100`"

So kindly help me how to get that `3 bits` also 
please help me

The code which i have written is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void main()
{
   int fd,a,n;
   fd =open("/dev/ttyUSB0",O_RDWR | ONOCTTY);
   if(fd==-1)
   {
         printf("\n error in opening the port \n");
   }
   else
         printf("port successfully opened");
    struct termios SerialPortSettings;
    tcgetattr(fd,&SerialPortSettings); 
    cfsetispeed(&SerialPortSettings,B115200); |
    cfsetospeed(&SerialPortSettings,B115200); 
    SerialPortSettings.c_cflag &= PARENB;
    SerialPortSettings.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    SerialPortSettings.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    SerialPortSettings.c_cflag |= CS8;
    SerialPortSettings.c_cflag &= CRTCTS;
    SerialPortSettings.c_cflag |= (CREAD | CLOCAL);
    SerialPortSettings.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);
    SerialPortSettings.c_iflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);
    tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&SerialPortSettings);
    char write_buffer[] = "A"; 
    int  bytes_written  =  0 ;   

    bytes_written = write(fd,write_buffer,sizeof(write_buffer));
    tcgetattr(fd, &SerialPortSettings);                           

    //Configure Baudrate()
   //Configure data bits()                                         

    SerialPortSettings.c_cflag |= CREAD | CLOCAL;//enable receiver

    /* Setting Time outs */                                       
    SerialPortSettings.c_cc[VMIN]  = 10; /* Read 10 characters */  
    SerialPortSettings.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;  /* Wait indefinitely   */
    tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&SerialPortSettings);
    char read_buffer[32];                
    int  i=0,bytes_read = 0;                 

    bytes_read = read(fd,&read_buffer,32);
    for (i=0;i<bytes_read;i++)
    {
           printf("Char read : %x\n",read_buffer[i]);
    }
```

Comment: I don't think anyone will be able to help you until you show some code and explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: ok Fine , here is my code .

Comment: It looks like you only enable the receiver *after* you have sent the data...